# Custom text pre-processing saved in Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

How to write custom text pre-processing that could be **saved** as part of a model?

Suppose that I would like to have two features:

1. auto-correct string input with some function. Words might change after this operation
2. do query expansion of string input, such that outcome text/tokens might contain few additional words(for which weights would be trained).

Something like this:

1. fl**i** to London -> Fl**y** to London
2. fly to London -> Fly to London **loc_city**

   -> this token would need to be in vocabulary in advance, which could be done

After steps 1 and/or 2, feed the result to TextVectorisation / Embedding layer ?

There is `standardize` callback, but I do not see obvious way of doing that with existing tf.string operations.

Ideally, there is a callback function / layer which accepts string(or tokens) and maps to another string(or string tokens).

Comment: Why not define your own custom layer?

Comment: Sure if that is a way to go. I am just not experienced with tensorflow as with other tools, don't know best way to approach this.
If it is not too much to ask, mind showing an example with a layer which returns first char of a string ? That would help a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first character of a string like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class StringLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(StringLayer, self).__init__()

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.squeeze(tf.strings.bytes_split(inputs), axis=1).to_tensor()[:, 0]

s = tf.constant([['next_string'], ['some_string']])
layer = StringLayer()
print(layer(s))
# tf.Tensor([b'n' b's'], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
```

Comment: No problem..`tf.strings` is actually quite powerful.